# retrieve data from couchdb

Tags: java, couchdb

I am new couchdb user and I am using lightcouch API.
currently, I can get data from couchdb, but what I can get is not I need. You can see the following code: username value and password value are stored, and these two values are needed to store into jsonarray.
***However, the problem is when I tried to print the data, it only showing me this:

{"id":"0a3f38cfc5ca45d6bcd76725faf5b917","key":"0a3f38cfc5ca45d6bcd76725faf5b917","value":{"rev":"1-32d4a8325e8995d0eddd5b2626b752df"}}.***
***The problem is that I can not get username and password***. BTW, another question is, when the servlet send jsonarray for example named data, how does the jquery get the message and username from data.

```
CouchDbProperties properties = new CouchDbProperties(
        "db_test",
        true,
        "http",
        "127.0.0.1",
        5984, null, null);


CouchDbClient dbClient2 = new CouchDbClient(properties);
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("username", "justin");
map.put("message", "hello world");
dbClient2.save(map);

List<JsonObject> jsonList = dbClient2.view("_all_docs").query(JsonObject.class);
for (int i=0; i< jsonList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(jsonList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: jsonList.get(i) is an object, perhaps you want to look at the object's fields?

Comment: @hexafraction Hi, seems there is no function for get the object's field

Answer (score 0):

You can have "views" specified in CouchDb, in that case instead of "_all_docs" you would give your view path "_design/something/_view/someview".
More about views https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views

Or look into "_all_docs?include_docs=true", since "_all_docs" does not return data itself, just documents info like ids.